How Do Turing's Reaction-Diffusion Models in "The Chemical Basis of Morphogenesis" Relate to Organic and Physical Chemistry?
I'm reading Alan Turing's "The Chemical Basis of Morphogenesis" and its reaction-diffusion models:
https://www.dna.caltech.edu/courses/cs191/paperscs191/turing.pdf
As far as I understand Turing proposed that chemical reactions and diffusion processes can lead to pattern formation in biological systems. Here are the key principles from his paper:

Reaction-Diffusion Systems: Chemical substances, termed morphogens, react together and diffuse through a medium.
Instability of Homogeneous States: A homogenous distribution of chemicals can become unstable and lead to pattern formation.
Stationary Patterns: Certain conditions allow for the emergence of stable, non-uniform concentration patterns.
Wavelength of Patterns: The patterns formed have specific wavelengths determined by the diffusion rates and reaction kinetics.
Scale and Form of Patterns: The size and shape of the patterns depend on the system's parameters and initial conditions.
Symmetry Breaking: Small perturbations can break the symmetry of a system, leading to the development of patterns.

I'm curious about the applications of these principles in biochemistry, particularly in photosynthesis and cellular respiration.

Photosynthesis: How can reaction-diffusion principles apply to the light-dependent reactions:
$$
   2 \text{H}_2\text{O} + 2 \text{NADP}^+ + 3 \text{ADP} + 3 \text{P}_i \rightarrow O_2 + 2 \text{NADPH} + 3 \text{ATP}
   $$
and the Calvin cycle:
$$
   6 \text{CO}_2 + 12 \text{NADPH} + 18 \text{ATP} \rightarrow C_6H_{12}O_6 + 12 \text{NADP}^+ + 18 \text{ADP} + 18 \text{P}_i
   $$
Specifically, how do reaction-diffusion dynamics influence the spatial and temporal regulation of these reactions?

Cellular Respiration: How might reaction-diffusion models explain spatial and temporal regulation in glycolysis:
$$
   C_6H_{12}O_6 + 2 \text{NAD}^+ + 2 \text{ADP} + 2 \text{P}_i \rightarrow 2 \text{C}_3H_4O_3 + 2 \text{NADH} + 2 \text{ATP} + 2 \text{H}_2O
   $$
and the citric acid cycle:
$$
   \text{Acetyl-CoA} + 3 \text{NAD}^+ + \text{FAD} + \text{ADP} + \text{P}_i + 2 \text{H}_2O \rightarrow 2 \text{CO}_2 + 3 \text{NADH} + \text{FADH}_2 + \text{ATP} + 2 \text{H}^+
   $$
How do Turing's principles of reaction kinetics and diffusion contribute to our understanding of these processes?


Any insights or related studies would be greatly appreciated!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction%E2%80%93diffusion_system#Two-component_reaction%E2%80%93diffusion_equations

Turing's model is only one of many for reaction-diffusion. I doubt it applies to your specific examples.

Just a warning that while this concept you are interested in is likely important and useful, just because you found a hammer not everything is a nail.
